# What is the Registry key for the Taskbar's color?

Tags: windows, windows-10, registry

For a while now, I've been trying to find the Registry key that changes the color of the Windows Taskbar, but everything I have found no longer works.

I am using [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) to track the changes between setting a new color, and below are all of the changed keys. I've tried a bunch of these, but all I've found is that `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM\AccentColor` changes the title bar color.

Here's the list of all the keys changed when setting a new color:

[image]

What is the Registry key to change the Windows 10 Taskbar color?

I am on the latest windows version (2004)

Comment: for windows 10? or what os?

Comment: The Taskbar changes pretty drastically from one version of Windows to another, so it is likely that Taskbar settings also change from one version to another.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes for windows 10 latest version (2004)

Comment: what do you need with the color?

Comment: @DanielA.White I need to be able to change the taskbar colour via the correct registry key

Comment: @Jacob that shouldn't be your responsibility. its up to the OS. you can force it with a policy: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1260185-group-policy-force-background-and-accent-color